# converting a string date into US format in java

Tags: java, date, date-formatting

I have the below code in which date come as string type and I have to set it in US format 
so below I have shown it

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat usOutputDate =  new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

and inside a method I have written the below code and inside  `dealDateString` the value is coming as `02-Mar-2015`

```
// dealDateString = 02-Mar-2015 
java.util.Date  dealDate = extractDate(dealDateString); 
//here its value get converted in US format that is 03/02/2015
String dd = usOutputDate.format(dealDate); 

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US); 
// ***issue comes here as it get back converted in US format ***
java.util.Date date =  format.parse(dd);
brokerInvoiceLineItem.setDealDate(new Date(date));
```

as shown in the above code that's it value inside `String dd` is `03/02/2015` but the issue comes at format variable where
its value get converted back in UK format which i do not want please advise how can i convert it in UK format as it
is already converted in US format previously stored inside `String dd`.

Comment: :S what is it thats happening in your case. can we have something clearer

Comment: so you want to convert to US format or UK..`please advise how can i convert it in UK format as it is already converted in US format previously stored inside string dd`, but title of your question says `converting a string date into US format in java`?

Comment: well inside format the value is UK format that is it is 02/03/2015 but it should be in US format that is it should be 03/02/2015 please advise how can i over come from this inside string dd it is already in format of 03/02/2015

Comment: @Hemang yeah apologies from my end but the issue rite now is that inside string dd it is perfect that is  03/02/2015 but whe i format it that is  DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);..inside this the issue is

Comment: and you want to format it back because you want it as `Mar-02-2015`?

Comment: no i want to store it as Feb-03-2015 that is MM/dd/yyyy format and inside string variable dd its value is 03/02/2015 i want this same value but when i going for DateFormat it is changing its value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this...

```
  try {
        //parsing date format
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

        String dealDateString = "02-Mar-2015";
        Date date = formatter.parse(dealDateString);
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();

        //converting date format for US
        SimpleDateFormat sdfAmerica = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        TimeZone tzInAmerica = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
        sdfAmerica.setTimeZone(tzInAmerica);

        String sDateInAmerica = sdfAmerica.format(date); // Convert to String first
        System.out.println("Date (String) : " + sDateInAmerica);

    } catch (Exception bug) {
        bug.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34504314/642706) by Silambarasan Poonguti and [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34504277/642706) by Ramesh Ponnada are both correct. But both are outdated, using the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Those classes have proven to be troublesome, confusing, and flawed.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `LocalDate`

These new classes include [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for handling a date-only value without time-of-day nor time zone. Though a LocalDate does not contain a time zone, be aware that a time zone is crucial in determining a date such as 'today'. The date is not the same around the world at any one moment, as a new day dawns earlier in the east.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

### Parsing A String

To parse a string, specify a coded pattern. This pattern is similar to that used in the old java.text.SimpleTextFormat but not exactly the same. So be sure to study the [java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) doc closely.

Note that we use a triple `M` to specify that we expect an abbreviation of the name of the day. This is the key to solving the problem in the Question.

Also note that we specify a Locale, which tells java.time the human language we expect for that abbreviated name of day.

```
String input = "02-Mar-2015";
Locale locale = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd-MMM-yyyy" ).withLocale ( locale );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse ( input , formatter );
```

Dump to console. By default the `toString` methods in java.time use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

```
System.out.println ( "localDate: " + localDate );
```

> localDate: 2015-03-02

### Generating A String

When generating a String representation of a date-time value, usually best to let java.time localize it for you rather than assume a specific format. The [java.time.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) package has classes for such work.

Note the call to `withLocale`. The Locale specifies two elements, the cultural norms for the expected format and the human language to use for the names of the day and the month. If you do not specify a Locale, the JVM’s current default Locale is implicitly applied. Better to be explicit, as the default can change at any moment.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate ( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale ( Locale.US );
String output = today.format ( formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "output: " + output );
```

> output: 12/29/15

If you insist on a specific format, specify a coded pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "MM/dd/yyyy" );
String output = today.format ( formatter );
```

> output: 12/29/2015

## Conversion

If you have a java.util.Date in hand, convert to java.time. An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant instant = myJUDate.toInstant();
```

Assign the time zone by which you want to form a date, yielding a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId ) ;
```

Then ask for a LocalDate to be generated, its value extracted from the ZonedDateTime.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code:

```
SimpleDateFormat ukDateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat usDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy", Locale.US);

java.util.Date  dealDate = ukDateFormat.parse("02-Mar-2015");
String dateInUSFormat = usDateFormat.format(dealDate);
System.out.println(dd); // Here you have date String in US format.
```

[Link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/) has many examples on how to work with date conversion in Java

Comment: the real issue is not this as you can see inside string dateInUSFormat  you can get the correct value that is 03/02/2015 but the issue comes if you are going to add this DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US); after that

Comment: Naresh, your question is not clear, can you be more specific on what is happening when you apply format again. and which line it is converted back to UK format. your code doesn't show the later part I belive

Comment: when i apply format on string dd it again back converted in UK format that's the issue

Comment: Accepted answer above gives the date at that particular time (UTC no source TZ specified)
So converting that way Feb 3rd 2015 00:00 hrs gives Feb 2nd 2015 20:00 hrs (depending on DST). Is that you want ?

Comment: yes now you got the point please advise how can i achieve the same please

Comment: answer by silambarasan does that, have you tried it?

Comment: tried but it does not work the format get converted back in UK format again