# Changing date format from Spanish Latin to American

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

is there a way to change the date format from Latin Spanish Short:

`22 Abr 2020`

to American format `04/22/2020`

I'm using several transformations using datetime, however the short month format (Abr for Abril...not April) seems to be a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try this method

```
try {
        //parsing date format
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

        String dealDateString = "02-Mar-2015";
        Date date = formatter.parse(dealDateString);
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();

        //converting date format for US
        SimpleDateFormat sdfAmerica = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        TimeZone tzInAmerica = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
        sdfAmerica.setTimeZone(tzInAmerica);

        String sDateInAmerica = sdfAmerica.format(date); // Convert to String first
        System.out.println("Date (String) : " + sDateInAmerica);

    } catch (Exception bug) {
        bug.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can check here [converting a string date into US format in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504131/converting-a-string-date-into-us-format-in-java)

Comment: Please insert OP's test string and show how your code handles that case.  The stated problem is dependent on the language translation.

Comment: Thanks...forgot to mention, Im using  python...what lib or framework are you using in the example provided? Seems to be Java...any idea how to do it in Python?

Comment: It’s not only Java (as also mentioned in the link at the bottom), it’s the old, poorly designed and long outdated Java classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `TimeZone`. IMHO there’s nothing helpful in this answer.